# Custom URL rewriting not working in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I use the code below in a Codeigniter htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)-vacation$ /search?location=$1
```

When i access it with the url `www.example.com/moscow-vacation`,
it gives me a 404 error.

I have used the above htaccess code in a core php application. It works fine there.

Comment: @olaf there is no method called location, i get the values from url using $this->input->get() and i am using index method of search controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you don't have a `search` script. If the script is named `search.php`, you can use this slightly modified rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)-vacation$ /search.php?location=$1
```

If you have a controller named `Search` with a method `location`, you can either rewrite directly to

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)-vacation$ index.php/search/location/$1
```

or try

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)-vacation$ search/location/$1
```